# Font Awesome Font not displaying inside php Function

Tags: css, wordpress

Due to a CDN conflict I need to replace the forward and back arrows in posts on my Wordpress blog with Font Awesome Icons.  My code isn't displaying the icon:

HTML in single.php:

```
    <div class="navigation pull-right"> 
    <?php
    previous_post_link('%link', "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x'></i>" );
    echo ' ';
```

CSS:

```
.navigation pull-right:previous_post_link .fa-chevron-left{
color: #939393;
border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 800;
line-height: 1;
margin-left: 3px;
padding: 7px;}
.navigation pull-right:previous_post_link a:hover .fa-chevron-left{
color: #1abb9c;
transition: all 200ms ease-in 0s}
```

(Sorry I'm doing this on a test site - but the display problem can be seen in Firefox here www.photomobil.co.il).

I've used this syntax elsewhere on the site successfully.  I checked and the code is OK.  It seems that because the HTML is inside a php function it doesn't do anything.

The theme's code:

```
   <i class='icon-right-open'>
```

displays the theme's fontello font.  But it doesn't display with my CDN setup on Firefox and IE.  Can someone please suggest how to get the Font Awesome to display inside a php function?

Thank you very much in advance!
Deborah